How to denormalize data in R?
I am self-learning forecasting models, and I would like to ask how to denormalize from ets() predicted normalized time series data.
My data is ibm from fpp package (Hyndman), and I have made the data into ts and have normalized it then to run exponential smoothing ets(), and have obtained predictions, and finally would like to denormalize it.
I used the following functions to normalize
  normalize <- function(x) {
      return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
  }
  normalized_ibm <- normalize(ibm_train)

And here run the ets() function, but have no idea how to revert/denormalize it back.
 ets_ibm<-ets(normalized_ibm)


Perhaps DMwR::unscale() or related.

First, it is not clear why you would want to normalize the data. The ets() function does not require it.
But if you want to normalize, you need to store the normalization parameters -- in this case the values of min(x) and max(x). Then you can simply reverse the transformation.
